# No such table when wanting to insert data on SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps

I used to insert 2 values/columns in my sqlite db(coordinates/markers to show them on map), today i wanted to add another column, i added it as usual but when wanting to launch map activity i have a logcat error as:

```
08-23 13:27:30.001: ERROR/Database(300): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: coord: , while compiling: INSERT INTO coord(longitude, latitude, description) VALUES(?, ?, ?);
```

To create the db+table i'm using this code:

public class MaBaseSQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
private static final String TABLE_COORD = "coord";
private static final String COL_ID = "ID";
private static final String COL_LATI = "latitude";
private static final String COL_LONGI = "longitude";
private static final String COL_DESCRI = "description";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "coord.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String CREATE_BDD = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_COORD + " ("
+ COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_LATI + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
+ COL_LONGI + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_DESCRI + "TEXT NOT NULL);";

MaBaseSQLite(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //on créé la table à partir de la requête écrite dans la variable CREATE_BDD
    db.execSQL(CREATE_BDD);
}
```

To insert values i'm using this code in other class:

```
public long insertCoordo(Coordo coordo){
        //Création d'un ContentValues (fonctionne comme une HashMap)
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(COL_LATI, coordo.getlati());
        values.put(COL_LONGI, coordo.getlongi());
        values.put(COL_DESCRI, coordo.getdescri());
        //on insère l'objet dans la BDD via le ContentValues
        return bdd.insert(TABLE_COORD, null, values);
    }
```

Example adding:

```
Coordo coordo = new Coordo(36.876673,10.325928, "TOTAL La Marsa");
CoordBd.insertCoordo(coordo);
```

And coordinates has 3 values as mentionned in this code in coordo() class:

```
public Coordo(Double lati, Double longi,String descri){
        this.lati = lati;
        this.longi = longi;
        this.descri= descri;
    }
```

What could be the problem with that?Why it can't insert values on the table cause it dodn't find it?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: do you have something in your logcat when you are creating the table? Try updating the dbversion to 2 (which should trigger onUpdate where you can drop + recreate the table) to check it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a column in SQLite is not just changing the SQL command to create it. You have to either `ALTER` it or `DROP` it and `CREATE` it again in your onUpgrade.

Then, you may have problems if you store doubles in `TEXT`. `REAL` is more adapted.

Comment: Do you mean that i have to drop all the table when adding or deleting columns ? I'm using this onUpgrade() func: `public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) { db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + "table_coordonnees" + ";"); onCreate(db); }`

Comment: Yes, almost all the errors are gone, i'm just having an error on query. I'll open a new topic for that ;)

Answer (score 1):

change the database version value to another and then compile and run

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; /// change the version here
```

Comment: I think this could be it. @andronienn did you try this?

Comment: I put 2 as version and i'm having : `08-23 13:46:32.140: ERROR/Database(2893): Failure 1 (no such table: coord) on 0x126af8 when preparing 'DROP TABLE coord;'.
` It always does not find this table coord. Perhaps a problem when creating it :\

Comment: Also, i'm having this just before all other logcat errors: `08-23 13:46:31.901: ERROR/ActivityThread(2893): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the ; from the end of your create table statement. I bet your create statement failed and this database does not exist - as SQLite tries to tell you.

In addition: Why do you use Text columns for your Double values?

I would suggest to go through a small SQL tutorial.

Comment: I removed ; and same problem. and do you mean that i change `TEXT NOT NULL` by `Double` ?

Comment: I mean you should read a SQL tutorial, definetely. Change text to real. Your table  does not exists. If this was an update to an existing database and your upgrade statements are part of onUpgrade() you need to change your database version to 2 as suggested in an other answer.

Comment: `public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + "table_coordonnees" + ";");
  onCreate(db);
 }` I dropped the previous db with its tables and created new one with desired table name. Having now a this error: `table coord has no column named description: , while compiling: INSERT INTO coord(longitude, latitude, description) VALUES(?, ?, ?);
` how there is not description column ?!weird..

Answer (score 1):

You need a space in the string literal just before TEXT:
    `+ COL_DESCRI + "TEXT NOT NULL);";`
should be:
    `+ COL_DESCRI + " TEXT NOT NULL);";`